# Where do I find alloys and elerium?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Alloy and Elerium are very common crafting materials, but I'm not sure how I acquire them.

How do I acquire more alloy and Elerium?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the early game, shooting down UFOs is going to be your only real source for these materials, so you're extremely limited to the amount of elerium and alloy you're able to acquire.

As you progress into the later game, the more advanced aliens, namely Heavy Floaters, Cyber Disks, and Sectopods, start to "drop" these items (or are built out of them).

In short, the only way to acquire these materials is to go on missions. Shooting down a UFO (or better yet, invading a landed UFO) is the surest way to get these rarities.

Comment: Does capturing the aliens have an impact on the amount of materials you receive?

Comment: @Wipqozn You can't capture Cyberdiscs and Sectopods, and I never caught a heavy floater, so I'm not sure.

Comment: it helps also if you start using the EMP cannon (assuming you have it) to shoot down ships.  This ensures that more materials remain intact